# Access web control values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages in ASP.NET 3.5 and I need to access/read the web controls values from the first page but on the second page. The second page is being displayed with a single link, there is not a post event or something like that.

I guess I should use ViewState but it looks so complicated for this task so please let me know a better way to achieve this.

P.S I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: this one will help you.. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Comment: @naveen, I'm going to take a look there, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick & "Dirty": A session variable which holds the info to pass.

On the first page:

```
Session["ValueToPassToOtherControl"] = "The value";
```

On the second page:

```
var value = Session["ValueToPassToOtherControl"];
```

Elegant: You need to manage your state in any way (via a static manager whose function is to store and retrieve that info, but that will be also variables). Problem is [HTTP is stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). So you need to bypass this limitation via some kind of storing and retrieving of the data.

You suggested the use of [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) but forget it, ViewState is the technique used by an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form across postbacks which isn't what's happening on your scenario.

Comment: I went with session variable because it was simple and quick. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you have two .aspx pages and you want one page to share information with the other page. Does the first page link to the second page?

I ask because there are a couple of approaches you could take. You could add parameters to a query string in the link to the second page with the information you are trying to send. You could also use the session to temporarily store the information.

For example:

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="www.<yoursite>.com/firstpage.aspx?eggs=1&bacon=yum" Text="Awesome Site" runat="server" />
```

In the second page you would have this in the codebehind in the Page_Load

```
string eggs = Request.QueryString["eggs"];
string bacon = Request.QueryString["bacon"];
```

Now you have the value from page one available in page two.

Another approach might be to use the Session like so:

Page one:

```
Session["bacon"] = "Yum";
```

Page two:

```
string bacon = (string)Session["bacon"];
```

However, I would advise against overusing session to pass information between pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way that using the QueryString jugglery and Session values.
You could just use the previous page property that is set during cross page posting.

Use an asp link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="myLink"
  NavigateUrl="~/Page2.aspx"
  target="_blank" Text="Go to page 2"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then on **Page2.aspx.cs**:

Get the values from the [Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) as follows:

```
TextBox txtUser = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtUser");
TextBox txtSomeValue = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtSomeValue");
```

Use these as you require in your second page.